# stopAllActions works but stopActionByTag does nothing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCRepeatForever action with a tag of 20. I call this:

```
  [player stopActionByTag:20];
```

Noting happens.

I call this:

```
  [player stopAllActions];
```

It stops. Any idea? The action is created like this and runs fine:

```
 CCRepeatForever *repeat=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];
 repeat.tag=20;

 [player runAction:repeat];
```

update: i also tried setting `animate.tag=21` and stopping that action by itself or in addition to the `repeat` action, but neither works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, I made a quick test with stopActionWithTag using CCRepeatForever and it stops it correctly.

I can only imagine two cases where it wouldn't work:

1. You have more than one action with the tag = 20 running on the same object.
2. The object you send runAction to is a different object than the one you send stopActionByTag to.

The former is easy to check. If this code fixes your problem, you're running multiple actions with the same tag on the player object:

```
while ([player getActionByTag:20]) {
    [player stopActionByTag:20];
};
```

The latter is rather unlikely but possible. One way to find out is to set a breakpoint on the runAction line and note the address of the player variable. Then set another breakpoint at the stopActionByTag line and compare that player's address with the previous one. If they're not the same, then that would be the problem.

Comment: very strange; your code does in fact work, but I have looked through every line and this is the only action I have assigned a tag number in the entire app, so there shouldn't be more than one.

Comment: Then maybe that action gets started while the old action is still running?

Comment: that was it! thanks. the action was in a method, called when that action is needed, and two different other methods were both calling that method, starting it twice. i put it in another method because it was the only "safe" way I could find to reuse actions.